# Read telegram channel messages

Tags: telegram

So I need to read all new messages of one specific channel that I'm in (not as an admin). I searched for different client apis (.NET, PHP, nodejs) but none of them helped.

Do you have any idea how I could do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Well that's the problem. Reading channel messages is really the only thing I want to do so i was hoping for a telegram client in C#, VB, PHP, Java or Nodejs that I can use for this.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73270188/8583692).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how i did it :

Install Telegram https://github.com/vysheng/tg

Install Cli wraper https://github.com/luckydonald/pytg

```
from pytg import Telegram
from pytg.utils import coroutine
tg      = Telegram(  telegram="./tg/bin/telegram-cli", pubkey_file="./tg/tg-server.pub")
receiver    = tg.receiver
QUIT = False
@coroutine
def main_loop():
  try:
    while not QUIT:
      msg = (yield) # it waits until it got a message, stored now in msg.
      if msg.text is None:
        continue
      print(msg.event)
      print(msg.text)
  except GeneratorExit:
    pass
  except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
  else:
    pass

receiver.start()
receiver.message(main_loop())
```

NodeJS version :

```
const path = require('path');
const TelegramAPI = require('tg-cli-node');
const config = {
    telegram_cli_path: path.join(__dirname, 'tg/bin/telegram-cli'), //path to tg-cli (see https://github.com/vysheng/tg)
    telegram_cli_socket_path: path.join(__dirname, 'socket'), // path for socket file
    server_publickey_path: path.join(__dirname, 'tg/tg-server.pub'), // path to server key (traditionally, in %tg_cli_path%/tg-server.pub)
}

const Client = new TelegramAPI(config)

Client.connect(connection => {
    connection.on('message', message => {
        console.log('message : ', message)
        console.log('message event : ', message.event)
        console.log('message text : ', message.text)        
        console.log('message from :', message.from)
    })
    connection.on('error', e => {
        console.log('Error from Telegram API:', e)
    })
    connection.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('Disconnected from Telegram API')
    })
})
```

Comment: is there a way to receive posts from a specific channel using pytg.

Comment: @ycode where is the channel you are receiving messages from? Or are you only receiving direct messages?

Comment: what is the socket file?

Answer (score 0):

Try Telethon.
https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon
It allows you to read messages as telegram user.

Comment: any affiliation? [/help/promotion](/help/promotion)

Answer (score -2):

First step is to add the telegram bot as channel admin if not you can't read channel messages!!!

Comment: If ypu can use python then you may wish to use telethon